# jQuery to append input of dynamically loaded Ajax select list to another form before submitting

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, select

For the question let me simplify my code:

I have two html forms with id's of 'header' and 'existing'

In the 'existing' form I have a select element where the options list is loaded dynamically using Ajax depending on the result of a search - this works fine with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#article').keyup(function() {
        var getData = 'q=' + this.value + '&s=' + $('#supplierCode').val();
        $.getJSON('article.php', getData, function(j) {
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }
            $('select#articleList').html(options);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

The search works and the list appears to be loaded correctly as part of the form. I then want the input data of this form to be combined with the data of the 'header' form before submitting. I use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#articleList').change(function() {
        $('#existing :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#header');
        $('#header').submit();
    });
});
```

But whatever I select from the options list the $_REQUEST data always shows the first item on the list as chosen.

I can add more code if this is necessary - but hopefully the esence of the problem is clear!

Comment: I'll go ahead and suggest that you use a library for such an operation. https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2 will be perfect for your needs.

Comment: What exactly is `$_REQUEST`? Are you talking php by any chance?

Comment: Yes, this is all part of a 500 line php script... I will take a look at Select2 - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to study the way [Select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) Jquery plugin works,

The plugin creates a list of items using `<ul>`s and stores the value of the chosen element in an `<input>`.

I believe this is done, so as to workaround the issue that you are having with dynamically populated `<select>` lists.

You can do the same as a solution to your issue.

Comment: Yes the whole restructuring of the input from `<select>` to normal `<input>` by using this plugin solved the problem. None of the other code had to be changed and I got much nicer dropdown menus. Two birds with one stone! Thanks ...

Comment: Glad to be of help. Tip: use plugins instead of self-built solutions, if possible. The plugins will be more robust and would have ironed, most, if not all the kinks of the daily programmer.